# JavaScript in DOM popup

Tags: javascript, silverstripe

**SilverStripe 2.4.7**

Hi

I have been reading this [tutorial](http://www.ssbits.com/snippets/2011/inserting-javascript-into-a-dom-popup/) and have tried to implement it but I am confused.  It doesn't seem to work but I'm not getting errors or anything.

My question is am I missing something like a module, etc?  I have implemented the code like so...

```
   JQ = jQuery.noConflict();
   JQ(document).ready(function() {
   // Find the select box, named differently on the update and add forms
   var sel = JQ('select[id="DataObjectManager_Popup_DetailForm_Status"]');
   if (sel.attr('id') == undefined) {
       sel = JQ('#DataObjectManager_Popup_DetailForm_Status');
   }

   // hide either the internal or external link editing box
   if (sel.val() == 'rejected' || 'Rejected') {
       JQ('#DataObjectManager_Popup_DetailForm_Reason').show();
   }  else {
       JQ('#DataObjectManager_Popup_DetailForm_Reason').hide();
   };

   // toggle boxes on drop down change
   sel.change(function(e) {
   if (sel.val() == 'rejected' || 'Rejected') {
     JQ('#DataObjectManager_Popup_DetailForm_Reason').show();
   }  else {
     JQ('#DataObjectManager_Popup_DetailForm_Reason').hide();
   };
 });
});
```

Nothing happens when I use the dropdown so do I need to install a module too or is there something else I'm missing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's a pretty bad tutorial, that is.

Comment: I am in full agreement.  Can you recommend a better one?

Comment: Well I don't have much context. That code depends on very specific HTML being present - those particular elements with those particular "id" values.  Note that jQuery does not consider it to be an error if your jQuery statements don't find the elements they're looking for.

Comment: Have you included the jQuery library? Have you tried putting `alert`s or `console.log`s throughout your code to see what actually executes?

Comment: Yes I did include it. I have since got it working to the extent that it receives a 200 ok from the remote server but displays a Javascript parse error in the CMS.  As far as I can tell this is a Silverstripe issue now, not a Javascript one anymore but thank you for the help.